# Looking for the name of a certain type of room

Tags: building-design, architecture

I don't know if this is the place to ask, but I am wondering about the name for a certain type of room in a building.

I am thinking about the ones where it is basically like a central room, but it is many floors tall of open space, with the different floors being cut off before it, or overhang it slightly.

https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/12/73/3b/7a/inside-courtyard-during.jpg

Like this, many floors tall of open space, but not opened to the sky. Courtyard kinda fits, but ultimately isn't what I mean, as Courtyard is very vague, and also means it is open to the sky. So what is it called when it is like what I am describing? Does it have a name at all?

I hope this explanation is good enough to get the idea across.

Edit: My question has been answered.

Comment: That's called an atrium.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah, I knew that term. For some reason it didn't come to mind. It was one of those cases where I knew, but couldn't remember. Thanks DKNguyen.